# .NET managed class for playing raw (PCM) audio stream?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, stream, pcm

Is there any managed class of .NET that allow playing a stream or array of short (16bit) with defined frequency, bit per sample and channels? The `SoundPlayer` class can only play a wav stream, which requires a file header.

In Android, there is a class named `AudioTrack` that can be instantiated like this:

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
11025, 
AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
musicLength, 
AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

to play a `short` type stream. Is there any .NET equivalence? In addition, I would happy to know if there is any .NET managed class for getting raw recording from a Windows audio input.

Comment: The .NET framework avoids getting too involved in the many media formats, that's a battle it cannot win.  You use a library for that, like NAudio.

Comment: Oh that's not cool! I thought PCM should not be considered as a "format" at all, it is just an array overall.